# What is the best way to handle and manage user permissions and access in my contract?

Tags: solidity, remix, dapp-development

As a smart contract developer, it's important to make sure that only authorized users are able to perform certain actions within the contract, while also maintaining the security of the contract and protecting it from malicious attacks.

Apart from openzplin any other best solution for this

Answer (score 0):

I normally use the Access Contract Library from Open Zeppelin, here you can find the info:
https://docs.openzeppelin.com/contracts/4.x/api/access

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

`AccessControl.sol` from Open Zeppelin is awesome way to do this

I normally use `DEFAULT_ADMIN_ROLE` ONLY for role management, leaving any other action under tight control.

Example Usage:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.9;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/access/AccessControl.sol";

contract MyContract is AccessControl {
    bytes32 public constant NEW_ROLE = keccak256("NEW_ROLE");
    bytes32 public constant ONE_MORE_ROLE = keccak256("ONE_MORE_ROLE");

    constructor() {
        _grantRole(DEFAULT_ADMIN_ROLE, msg.sender);
        _grantRole(NEW_ROLE, msg.sender);
        _grantRole(ONE_MORE_ROLE, msg.sender);
    }
}
```